# SQL Server '=' returns no rows when rows exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure why a SQL Server stored procedure is storing the wrong `ID` value for a column which makes the stored procedure return zero rows when two rows exist.

When executing the select statement outside of the stored procedure I get the results that I am looking for, but this is being used by another application and I do not want to hard code the select statement, I want to use the stored procedure since the procedure is used in many parts of the application.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('GET_ENABLE_OBJ_SP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC GET_ENABLE_OBJ_SP
GO

CREATE PROC GET_ENABLE_OBJ_SP   
    @COURSE VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @OBJ    VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @DEPT_DES VARCHAR(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @COURSE_ID INT;
    DECLARE @OBJ_ID INT;
    DECLARE @DEPT_ID INT;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT DEPT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT 
               WHERE DEPT_DESIGNATOR = @DEPT_DES)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @DEPT_ID = DEPT_ID 
        FROM DEPARTMENT 
        WHERE DEPT_DESIGNATOR = @DEPT_DES;
    END

    PRINT 'DEPARTMENT ID: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DEPT_ID);
    PRINT 'DEPT DESIGNAT: ' + @DEPT_DES;

    IF @COURSE IS NULL
        RAISERROR('MUST SUPPLY A COURSE DESIGNATOR', 11, 1);

    IF @OBJ IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('MUST SUPPLY AN OBJECTIVE DESIGNATOR', 11, 1);

    -- FIND THE COURSE
    IF EXISTS (SELECT COURSE_ID FROM COURSE 
               WHERE COURSE_DESIGNATOR = @COURSE AND DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @COURSE_ID = COURSE_ID 
        FROM COURSE 
        WHERE COURSE_DESIGNATOR = @COURSE AND DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID;
    END

    PRINT 'COURSE_ID:  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @COURSE_ID);
    PRINT 'COURSE DES:  ' + @COURSE;

    IF @COURSE_ID IS NULL
        RAISERROR('COURSE DOES NOT EXISTS', 11, 1);

    IF EXISTS (SELECT CTO_ID FROM COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
               WHERE COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @OBJ_ID = CTO_ID 
        FROM COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
        WHERE COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID AND DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID;
    END

    PRINT 'OBJECTIVE ID: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @OBJ_ID);
    PRINT 'OBJ DESIGNAT: ' + @OBJ;

    IF @OBJ_ID IS NULL
        RAISERROR('OBJECTIVE IS INVALID OR DOES NOT EXIST', 11, 1);
    ELSE
        IF EXISTS (SELECT CEO_ID FROM COURSE_ENABLE_OBJECTIVE 
                   WHERE CTO_ID = @OBJ_ID AND COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID)
        BEGIN 
            SELECT 
               E.CEO_DESIGNATOR, E.CEO_DESCRIPTION
            FROM 
               COURSE_ENABLE_OBJECTIVE E
            JOIN 
               COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE T ON E.COURSE_ID = T.COURSE_ID 
                                           AND E.CTO_ID = T.CTO_ID
            WHERE 
               E.COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID 
               AND T.CTO_ID = @OBJ_ID;
         END
END
GO
```

Here is the execution statement I used to call it and the statement to select all of the values for that table for the selected "department" and "course"

```
begin try
    exec GET_ENABLE_OBJ_SP '201', '1.0.0', 'CIS'
    EXEC GET_OBJECTIVES '201', 'CIS'

    SELECT * 
    FROM COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
    WHERE COURSE_ID = 6

    SELECT * 
    FROM COURSE_ENABLE_OBJECTIVE 
    WHERE COURSE_ID = 6
end try
begin catch
    PRINT  'ERROR' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER());
    PRINT 'MESSAGE: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
end catch
```

I can return all of the values using a select statement and hard coding the values in place but it returns rows that are not belonging, here is a screenshot of the values returned and the 'print' statements that are in the stored procedure. for some reason it returns the @obj_id(CTO_ID) as 4 when it is supposed to be 1. My objective is to return the correct CEO_ID columns in the below result set where the CTO_ID = 1 and the COURSE_ID = 6. The stored procedure, as you can see in the messages is marking the designator I passed in ('1.0.0') as belonging at ID 4, clearly from the result set it is in ID 1 and not 4, what would cause this?

[image: Result_Set.jpg]

[image: Messages.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
SELECT @OBJ_ID = CTO_ID 
FROM COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
WHERE COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID AND DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID;
```

matches 4 rows in your `COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE` table. If you want it just to match CTO_ID = 1, then you need to narrow your WHERE clause.

It should be

```
SELECT @OBJ_ID = CTO_ID 
FROM COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
WHERE COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID AND DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID 
  AND CTO_DESIGNATOR = @OBJ;
```

Comment: I did that. the result is still the same. the problem with that is that the course_designator that is used to get the course_id from the database is a number and that can be used among multiple departments, so can the CTO_ID and the CEO_ID. the DEPT_ID is what defines the location of the specific one that is there, but the Stored Proc is still setting this to value 4 for the CTO_ID when value 4 is '4.0.0' when the value compared is '1.0.0'

Comment: No, I mean you need to add "AND CTO_DESIGNATOR = @OBJ" to that statement. Then you will get the right row.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the reason:

```
SELECT 
  @OBJ_ID = CTO_ID 
FROM 
  COURSE_TERMINAL_OBJECTIVE 
WHERE
  COURSE_ID = @COURSE_ID AND
  DEPT_ID = @DEPT_ID;
```

You have 4 rows that have course_id 6 and dept_id 1. The result is that the last id from the select is the one that remains in the variable.

Maybe you're missing the cto_designator? Or if you want to have the first, you should have select top 1 + order by to guarantee which one you actually need to have.

You also have quite strange logic with the "if exists", you have only course_id there, but you're fetching with dept_id too.

Comment: I'm using the CTO_ID to retrieve the CEO_ID that is matched to it. I pass the CTO_Designator in as a parameter, '1.0.0' and SQL Server matched it up as '4.0.0' in row 4 and not in row 1 which is causing me to not return the CEO_ID in the bottom result set that is mapped to '1.0.0' in the second result set... The CTO_Designator, course_designator and dept_designator are used as parameters to filter the result set to the proper course. the course_designators can be used only once per department and the CTO_designators only once per course, and the dept_designators only once in the whole database

Comment: I don't really follow... but you're probably missing a search criteria? You're only fetching using 1 and 6, not with 1.0.0 -- and that's why you get wrong results.

Comment: And that is the parameter @OBJ that you don't use in the search at all.

Comment: Yes, the guy above made that clear earlier, that solved the problem. thank you for the help

Comment: @JamesZ Gave you an upvote. You took the time and had the right answer, I posted just slightly before you.